# How to close GLUT Window when input_raw() is active? Python

Tags: python, glut

This might be a silly question, but I couldn't figure this out on my own neither have I find the solution on line. I have a PyOpenGl application that uses GLUT to create its window. The program is supposed to continue running while the user input in the **TERMINAL** is not "quit". Something like this:

```
command = raw_input()
while command != "quit":
    if command == "add_shape":
        draw_cube()
    elif command == "remove_shape":
        clear_window()
    elif command == "add_light":
        add_light()
    command = raw_input()
sys.exit("Application closed by the user")
```

The problem is that when I can `raw_input()` closing the window using the "x" button doesn't work, only typing quit would terminate the task. At first I thought GLUT would have a callback function for closing window that I could use to detect the "x" button click and force terminate the application, turns out it does have such a function void `glutCloseFunc(void(*)(void)callback)` but it is not called while `raw_input()` is active. So what is a good solution for this? How can I read user input from the terminal and still be able to close my application by clicking the "x" button?

REQUIRED:

- Read user input from the terminal.

OPTIONAL:

- Using GLUT is optional. I've tried with PyGame, but couldn't find a solution to read from the terminal since it only treats interactions with the window.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the most logic and easy way to do it, is with the use of threads. SO you would have one thread to listen to raw_inputs() and another thread to listen to the window close event.